# Воспроизвести звучание слова

Tags: google-translate, text-to-speech

Я хочу с помощью `Google Translatate API` получить звучание слова. То есть пользователь вводит какое-то слово на английском. И нужно, чтобы была возможность произнести это слово на каком-либо другом языке (задается пользователем). В самом Google-переводчике такая возможность есть. Как это сделать через API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Официального Google Voice API нет. Давно ожидается, но пока еще нет. Есть неофициальные для разных языков:

1. Для [C# (dot NET)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gvoicedotnet/)
2. Для [Java (Android)](http://code.google.com/p/google-voice-java/)
3. Для [Python](http://code.google.com/p/pygooglevoice/)